# Pre-push git hook produces unknown hash when pushing tags

Tags: git

I have the following python code as part of my `pre-push` git hook:

```
import sys
lines = sys.stdin.read().splitlines()
for line in lines:
    local_ref, local_sha1, remote_ref, remote_sha1 = line.split()
    print(local_sha1)
```

When I push a tag, for example:

```
git tag -a v1.0 -m "v1.0"
git push
```

The sha1 printed from my `pre-push` hook does not exist in the commit history of my repository. What does this sha1 represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the ID of the tag, specifically, the annotated tag object.  You'll get a huge hint / give-away if you print the `local_ref` as well!

Comment: Ah I see, the local ref gave me `refs/tags/v1.0`